single div position using flexbox
I'm trying to make the image div is centered, and bot section stick to bottom.

I also used justify-content: flex-end, but image div does not want to change its position at all
What i try


.box
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
 
}

  .image 
  {
    align-self: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
  }

  .bot-section
  {
    width: 100%;
    align-self: flex-end; 
  }
<div class="box">
 <div class="image"></div>
 <div class="bot-section">
    <div class="text"></p></div>
    <div class="progress"></div>
 </div>
</div>




I have turned your code into a snippet but it displays nothing, could you try to amend the snippet to display what you currently have so it can be debugged? Also note that if your flex-direction is column, align-items and justify-content flips meanings as the axis has changed.

Your HTML is invalid <div class="text"></p>

My bad. Check please here https://onlinegdb.com/857QXXP1o

Just edit your css as follows:
.box
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
 
}

  .bot-section {
    width: 100%;
    align-self: flex-end;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    
  }


Its my pleasure



.box {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: grey;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color:red;
}

.bot-section {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
}
<div class="box">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="bot-section">
    <div class="text"></div>
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
</div>



That's what I came up with, I used smaller heights because with a large percetage value for the image div it began to like they were connected. I hope it helps
